# How to make smoothest affix to bottom navbar?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, affix

I'm trying to align what would be a fixed bottom navbar to affix top navbar. I first tried to use the offset option within a data attribute, then I chose to use a different format. I've tried adjusting the header size, but concerned about the image not breaking to point that seems appropriate within mobile view.

Can't seem to make smoothest transition possible within 2 pixels. E.g. https://www.aspiration.com/

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#nav').affix({
          offset: {
            top: $('header').offset().top
          }
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
header {
    height:630px;
}

#nav.affix {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index:10;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body id="home">
  <header>
    <section>
      <img>
    </section>
  </header>

  <!-- Begin Navbar -->
  <div id="nav">
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static">
      <div class="container">
        <!-- .btn-navbar is used as the toggle for collapsed navbar content -->
        <a class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bar"></span>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bar"></span>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bar"></span>
        </a>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav pull-right navbar-nav">
            <li>
              <form class="navbar-form">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
                </button>
              </form>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-flag"></i> <span class="badge">2</span></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar -->
  </div>

  <section>
    BELOW the navbar
    <img>
  </section>
```

Comment: Although you posted the relevant HTML, CSS and JS, it would be very helpful if you created a jsfiddle or plunker that replicates your problem so StackOverflow can help you better.

Comment: @yvesmancera how hard is it to make a jsbin?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/tuhacehigi/edit?html,output